# Using PIVOT sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot

I have the following table:

Table1

| COD_USER | DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | active |
| 1 | 2020-06-30 | inactive |
| 1 | 2020-12-01 | active |

With this data I needed to generate the following output:

Table2

| COD_USER | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-06-30 |
| 1 | 2020-12-01 | NULL |

I'm trying to use PIVOT for this but I don't know if it will be possible.

Comment: Well, show what you tried, and explain what problem you're having that makes you think it might not be possible

Comment: What if there are two consecutive active? Or two consecutive inactive?

Answer (score 1):

The part a PIVOT won't help with is pairing the records up (one start/active and one end/inactive).

If you know that you'll ALWAYS get the records alternating between active and inactive (so never get `active, active, inactive`), and ALWAYS starts with active, this would give each pair of records the same sequence number, which you can group by.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [COD_USER], [STATUS]
                           ORDER BY [DATE]
                      )
                        AS SEQ
  FROM
    Table1
)
SELECT
  [COD_USER],
  MAX(CASE WHEN [STATUS] =   'active' THEN [DATE] END)   AS START_DATE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [STATUS] = 'inactive' THEN [DATE] END)   AS END_DATE
FROM
  sorted
GROUP BY
  [SEQ]
```

***EDIT***

A similar approach to deal with any arbitrary order of statuses...

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG([STATUS])
      OVER (PARTITION BY [COD_USER]
                ORDER BY [DATE]
      )
        AS PREV_STATUS,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY [COD_USER]
                ORDER BY [DATE]
      )
        AS SEQ
  FROM
    Table1
)
SELECT
  [COD_USER],
  MAX(CASE WHEN [STATUS] =   'active' THEN [DATE] END)   AS START_DATE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [STATUS] = 'inactive' THEN [DATE] END)   AS END_DATE
FROM
  sorted
GROUP BY
  [SEQ] - CASE WHEN [STATUS] = 'inactive' AND [PREV_STATUS] = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

It the statuses always properly interleave, I would recommend `lead()`:

```
select cod_user, date as start_date, end_date
from (
    select t.*
        lead(date) over(partition by cod_user order by date) as end_date
    from mytable t
) t
where status = 'active'
order by cod_user, date
```